# Does IETF recognize the IPFS URI format?

Tags: uri, ipfs, rfc, ietf

Does any part of the Internet Engineering Task Force recognize (even in draft form) the URI naming specification that IPFS is using (i.e. `ipfs://` URIs)?

I have looked for RFCs and not found any.

There seems to be significant built support for IPFS but the specification still seems to be only published by a single organization, Protocol Labs (IPFS) and not by standards bodies. I'm asking because it seems like I am searching about this wrong.

Answer (score 0):

IPFS is listed in the IANA URI Scheme registry as provisionally registered. See https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/prov/ipfs